# ObjC: object returned empty description?

Tags: objective-c

My code is reading a list of key/value pairs like follows:

```
A:nodeAbc
...
Q:node2
R:
T:node3
...
```

Each pair is split using NSString:componentsSeparatedByString:

```
NSArray *kv = [@"R:" componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
```

In the list example above, R has no matching value. As I ask to print it, here is what I get:

(lldb) po [kv objectAtIndex:1]
(id) $33 = 0x00007fff77a888e0

How can I identify this?

```
if ([kv objectAtIndex:1]) // returns YES
```

I'd like it to be treated as a nil, how can it be done?
Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's not nil, it's an empty string (read the docs, it's stated there). What you want is

```
if ([[kv objectAtIndex:1] length] > 0)
```